# How to use Rails 3's ActiveSupport core extensions outside Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activesupport

I'm having a problem using ActiveSupport's core extensions on a gem I am developing.

I had it working with AS 2.3.8, but as soon as I wanted to port it to 3b4, the extensions stopped working and my test results are filled with lines such as:

```
undefined method `blank?' for "something":String
```

I've included it via

```
gem "activesupport"
```

followed by

```
require "active_support"
```

Is there anything else I need to call to include those extensions?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

ActiveSupport is more separate now in Rails 3.

If you want the all active_support thing, you can `require 'active_support/all'` now.

But if you want only the `blank?` method, you can try

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
```