# cattr_accessor not working (outside rails) when active_support is required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I'm not familiar with active_support, so bear with me!

[Fox's library](http://github.com/fox/google_search) allows searching via google's APIs, but it requires active support. i can't seem to get it working though! Any ideas?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
require 'google_search'

p GoogleSearch.web :q => "Hello World!"
```

Gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method ‘cattr_accessor’ for GoogleSearch:Class
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With more googling I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053119/use-rails-3s-activesupport-core-extensions-outside-rails) - seems to work for me!

I'm now requiring: `require 'active_support/all'`

I hope this helps someone!