# Converting a 12 hour time string with AM/PM to 24 hour time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of time based strings saved per object in my db that are formatted like this:

```
"01:00 PM"
```

Doing a little bit of research I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001598) that shows you how to convert a string similar to but not exactly how mine is. The difference being the example has no colon in between the hour and minute integers, which throws a snag in the answer's conversion:

```
Time.strptime("1:00 PM", "%I%P").strftime("%H:%M")
# ArgumentError (invalid strptime format - `%I%P')
```

Is there still a way to get this conversion to work given my particular format?

Comment: Converting `12:00 PM` to `12:00` might not be the best example.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: `12` exists in both, the 12-hour and the 24-hour clock. It would be more obvious to pick an example like `01:00 PM` → `13:00` or `11:00 PM` → `23:00`.

Comment: Oh okay I gotchu. Thanks for pointing this out. I’ll update in a few.

Comment: Just a note that you don't have to use `Time` methods (but it's simpler if you do): `if str.end_with?('AM'); str.sub(/ PM/,''); else; hr, min = str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i); "%d:%02d" % (60*hr + min + 12*60).divmod(60); end`. If, for example, `str = "1:07 PM"`, this returns `"13:07"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?
`time = "12:00 PM"`

`Time.strptime(time, "%I:%M %P").strftime("%H:%M")`

Comment: With this I get the error: `ArgumentError (invalid strptime format - '%I%M%P')`

Comment: do you use exact `"%I:%M %P"` as second argument? there is semicolon and space between `%M` and `%P`

Comment: I also recommend checking this doc: https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime it has full set of options for `strftime`. Differences between strftime and strptime are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619494/how-to-understand-strptime-vs-strftime (pretty same, in short)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the format of time in strptime method so you have to pass `'%I:%M %P'` and if you don't want semicolon in time than you have to pass the values according to it in strftime method as `'%H%M'` so you'll get your answer as you requirement.

`Time.strptime('10:00 PM', '%I:%M %P').strftime("%H%M")`
this will give you output `"2200"` and

`Time.strptime('10:00 PM', '%I:%M %P').strftime("%H:%M")`
this will give you output `"22:00"`.

Thank You.