# How do I set date time to 1 month ago with DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am trying to use set Google Analytics start date and end date to capture unique visitors within the last 30 days.  I have made `end_date = DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`, how do I set `start_date` to 30 days ago.

Comment: We need to see sample code showing what you've tried. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Problem is not al moths are 30 days. Any solution for this, I wonder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're going too far with your creation of `end_date`.

You're turning it into a string, which has no math capabilities. Instead, leave it as a DateTime and you inherit the ability to [add and subtract integers](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) to do date math:

```
require 'date'

datetime_now = DateTime.now
end_date = datetime_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # => "2013-08-06"
end_date.class # => String

end_date = datetime_now # => #<DateTime: 2013-08-06T14:55:20-07:00 ((2456511j,78920s,731393000n),-25200s,2299161j)>
end_date - 30 # => #<DateTime: 2013-07-07T14:55:20-07:00 ((2456481j,78920s,731393000n),-25200s,2299161j)>
```

Notice that `end_date - 30` returns a DateTime that is exactly 30 days earlier; The time component is preserved. Convert the value to a string once you have the value you want.

Answer (score 5):

I realise this question is very old, but here's a clean way to do it for anyone who needs to know:

```
start_date = (Date.now - 30.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

or

```
start_date = (Date.now - 1.month).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

You can do similar things with `DateTime.now`, and `Time.now`

Comment: I think this needs `active_support/time` or rails?

Answer (score 3):

With basic Ruby you can do this:

```
> irb
require 'date' # needed
today_minus_30  = Date.today.to_date - 30

# if you need the date as a string
date_as_string = today_minutes_30.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated per Tin Man's suggestion:

In Ruby:

```
require 'date'
end_date = DateTime.now
start_date = end_date - 30
formatted_end_date = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
formatted_start_date = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

In Rails or if `active_support/time` is required:

Use the days and ago methods:

```
start_date = 30.days.ago
```

Here is the code:

```
end_date = DateTime.now
start_date = end_date - 30.days
formatted_end_date = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
formatted_start_date = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This way start_date is exactly 30 days before end_date.  If you instantiate two DateTimes, they will not be exactly 30 days apart.

The `days` and `ago` methods can be accessed outside of a Rails environment with this line:

```
require 'active_support/time'
```

Comment: You might want to explain where `days` and `ago` come from and how they can be included. The OP is using straight Ruby so those aren't available.

Comment: @theTinMan - I agree with your comment and updated my answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: No, no, no, don't recommend loading the entire Active Support code base, just to cherry-pick a few needed methods. Use the core extensions for [Date](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date), [DateTime](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-datetime) and [Time](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time). Matter of fact, read "[How to Load Core Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#how-to-load-core-extensions)".

Comment: @theTinMan - updated again and thanks for the comment.  I couldn't get `require 'active_support/core_ext/date.rb'` to work, but found the `require 'active_support/time'` workaround on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238867/how-do-i-use-activesupport-core-extensions  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a helper method for that. Something like

```
# Gets time range for x number timeunits ago
  def time_range(unit, timeunit = nil)
    if timeunit == "weeks"
      now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week
    elsif timeunit == "months"
      now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month
    else
      now = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
    end
    # Ex: time_range(0, "days") --> Get the time range for today  between the beginning of today and the beginning of tommorow - 1 second
    now - unit.send(timeunit)..now + 1.send(timeunit) - 1.seconds - unit.send(timeunit)
  end
```

will help you to request time ranges. So when you request something like;

```
time_range(0, "months")
```

it will return the time range for 0 months ago (this month);

```
Thu, 01 Sep 2016 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Fri, 30 Sep 2016 23:59:59 UTC +00:00
```

And then you can simply query the database object and count everything within the range with;

```
Visit.where(started_at: time_range(unit, timeunit)).count
```