# Refactoring Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, refactoring

I have three arrays, two of which come from JSON.

I need to check if each array is not nil and the count is greater than 0. If any are greater than 0 display "Hello World" else display "Boo".

```
<% if !@arrayOne.nil? && @arrayOne.count > 0 || !@user_json[:user_stuff].nil? && @user_json[:user_stuff].count > 0 || !@user_json[:more_user_stuff].nil? && @user_json[:more_user_stuff].count > 0 %>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
  <% else %>
<h1>Boo</h1>
<% end %>
```

I need some help refactoring this code and would like to learn other ways to approach this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array.blank?` (assuming you're using Rails of course) to check whether an array is nil or empty, such as:

```
<% if !@arrayOne.blank? || !@user_json[:user_stuff].blank? || !@user_json[:more_user_stuff].blank? %>
```

Rule of thumb you should move as much logic to the controller as you can.

---

As suggested in the comments, you can also use `present?`, which is the same as `!blank?`, improving readability a bit:

```
<% if @arrayOne.present? || @user_json[:user_stuff].present? || @user_json[:more_user_stuff].present? %>
```

Comment: If the `@arrayOne` is `nil`, this will throw `NoMethodError: undefined method 'blank?' for nil:NilClass`. (Same for `@user_json[:user_stuff]`, `@user_json[:more_user_stuff]`)

Comment: @falsetru do you mean if @arrayOne etc are `undefined`? AFAIK `blank?` tests for nil before testing empty, such that `nil.blank?` returns true.

Comment: @falsetru [blank?](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) is a Rails API function, not a Ruby core function. Calling blank? in irb will in fact result in the undefined error.

Comment: `!foo.blank?` could be written as `foo.present?`. What reads much nice IMHO.

Comment: It's not necessary to use Rails to take advantage of `blank?` or `present?`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238867/how-do-i-use-active-support-core-extensions/4239625#4239625.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
<% if [!@arrayOne, @user_json[:user_stuff], @user_json[:more_user_stuff]].all? { |x|
  x && x.count > 0
} %>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
if [@arrayOne, @user_json[:user_stuff], @user_json[:more_user_stuff]].any?(&:present?)
```

In a next step I would move that condition into a helper with a nice name. Unfortunately you did not provide why you need this check (that why would hint a good name). But as an idea:

```
# in a helper
def something_to_show?
  [ @arrayOne, @user_json[:user_stuff], @user_json[:more_user_stuff]
  ].any?(&:present?)
end

# in the view
<% if something_to_show? %>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
<% else %>
  <h1>Boo</h1>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way that doesn't require Rails:

```
puts [a, b, c].map(&:to_a).all?(&:empty?) ? 'Boo' : 'Hello World'
```